# how to refactor function to return only 1 True value in a list?

Tags: python, refactoring

The function should print 1 of 4 categories - A,B,C,D. Is there way to refactor it more elegantly?

```
def get_category(hp):
    A = hp % 4 == 1
    B = hp % 4 == 3
    C = hp % 4 == 2
    D = hp % 4 == 0
    if A:
        print('A')
    if B:
        print('B')
    if C:
        print('C')
    else:
        print('D')
```

I want to somehow make the if clauses smaller and make it oneliner.

like this:

```
result_list = [A,B,C,D]

return filter(True, result_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because each of your `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` values are comparisons based on what could be used as an array index, you can just use an array for your outputs and index based on the result of `hp % 4`:

```
>>> def get_category(hp):
...     print(['D','A','C','B'][hp % 4])
...
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print(i,end=':\t')
...     get_category(i)
...
0:      D
1:      A
2:      C
3:      B
4:      D
5:      A
6:      C
7:      B
8:      D
9:      A
```